# dojo.connect is not working inside a loop. It only keeps the last time I did it

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi here is my function

```
function connectAccordionTabbing() {
    for(var i = 0; i < coverageStates.length;i=i+3){
        var jsState = coverageStates[i]+coverageStates[i+1];
        var firstNode = dijit.getFirstInTabbingOrder(document.getElementById('liabCovBlock_'+jsState));
        var lastNode  = dijit.getLastInTabbingOrder(document.getElementById('liabCovBlock_'+jsState));
        dojo.connect(firstNode, "onkeypress", function(evt) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                setAccordionTabOffFields(evt,jsState, true);
            }, 10); 
        });
        dojo.connect(lastNode, "onkeypress", function(evt) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                setAccordionTabOffFields(evt,jsState, false);
            }, 10); 
        });
    }
}
```

It loops through and goes through each state and makes the first and last nodes inside a block have connections during the page load.  The problem I am having is that when I am on one of those nodes and press a key it calls `setAccordionTabOffFields` but it thinks my state is the last state even if I was on the third state.  It does that in Chrome and IE but in firefox it does not even call the setAccordionTabOffFields.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a global var to store your dojo events (In your loop, add the dojo connect objects to the global var):

```
var formEvents = [];

formEvents.push(dojo.connect(dojo.connect(lastNode, "onkeypress", function(evt) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setAccordionTabOffFields(evt,jsState, false);
        }, 10););
```

or

```
function connectAccordionTabbing() {
    for(var i = 0; i < coverageStates.length;i=i+3){
        var jsState = coverageStates[i]+coverageStates[i+1];
        var firstNode = dijit.getFirstInTabbingOrder(document.getElementById('liabCovBlock_'+jsState));
        var lastNode  = dijit.getLastInTabbingOrder(document.getElementById('liabCovBlock_'+jsState));
        formEvents.push(dojo.connect(firstNode, "onkeypress", function(evt) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                setAccordionTabOffFields(evt,jsState, true);
            }, 10); 
        }););
        formEvents.push(dojo.connect(lastNode, "onkeypress", function(evt) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                setAccordionTabOffFields(evt,jsState, false);
            }, 10); 
        }););
    }
}
```

When cleaning up, don't forget about the global:

```
//Disconnect Dojo events
for (var x=2;x < formEvents.length;x++) {
  var handle = formEvents[x];
  dojo.disconnect(handle);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that but I am still getting the same result.  Any other ideas I should attempt?